# How to set textbox width depending of text length in ActiveReports

Tags: c#, textbox, activereports, componentone, grapecity

is there a property to set the width of a textbox so that it will grow/shrink in order to it´s text length? I don´t want to calculate a length/width ratio constant..
Thanks,
Walter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps then you may want to check the [ShrinkToFit](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR8Help/AR8_HelpOnlineEN/ShrinkTexttoFitinTextboxControl.html) property which reduces the size of the text so that it fits within the bounds of the control.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for using ActiveReports.
The CanGrow and CanShrink only work on the height.   ActiveReports operates -like other report engines- on the premise that report width is fixed and the controls grow vertically only.

Comment: There is a use case when growing and shrinking the width is necessary. For instance, there is a label/text box pair aligned to the right of the report and the label must move to the left in conjunction as the text box grows in width, expanding left.

Comment: In that case the textbox width or label should always have enough width to handle the widest it can be.   Again, since reports have a fixed page width with n number of pages, the assumption is that all items grow vertically.   The only exception is the matrix control which grows horizontally across pages based on the number of columns (dynamic)  it is certainly the most complex and least performant component.   Technically it might be possible to implement an option to grow width but IMO performance would be a concern for all reports.